# Where can I camp when driving Highway 37 in British Columbia, Canada?

Tags: canada, car-camping

I plan on driving to Alaska via the Stewart-Cassiar Highway (Highway 37) in British Columbia, Canada. Where can I legally camp along or near the highway?

Answer (score 4):

The Milepost Guidebook has [a list of points of interest](http://www.milepost.com/highway_info/cassiar_highway) along the Stewart-Cassiar Highway, which includes campgrounds.

> - J 2.5 Cassiar RV Park to west.
> - J 96.5 Meziadin Lake Provincial Park; camping.
> - J 97.5 Meziadin Junction. Junction with BC Highway 37A which leads west  38 miles to 5th Avenue, the main street of  STEWART, BC (pop. 699). Road continues across international border (must stop at customs) to HYDER, AK (pop. 100); camping, general store.  Dining and lodging in Stewart at the King Edward Hotel & Motel. Camping just outside Stewart at Bear River RV Park, turn at Mile 36.9 on Highway 37A. Attractions: Historic buildings in Stewart, Fish Creek bear viewing, Bear Glacier, Salmon Glacier.
> - J 155 Bell 2 Lodge; food, lodging, camping, propane, gas, diesel and pay phone.
> - J 227.1 Kinaskan Provincial Park; camping.
> - J 254.1 Mountain Shadow RV Park & Campground.
> - J 298.1 Dease Lake Lions Tanzilla River Campground; 15 natural wooded RV sites plus tent sites; picnic tablels, firepits.
> - J 310 Water’s Edge Campground.
> - J 374.9 JADE CITY (pop. 50); Cassiar Mountain Jade Store; jade cutting demonstrations, 5-room hotel, free overnight camping (no services).
> - J 397.2 Boya Lake Provincial Park: campground 1.2 miles east of highway.

I've traveled this highway with my family a couple of times, although it was quite a few years ago so I don't remember all of the details. I remember camping at Boya Lake and seeing loons and owls there, and I definitely recall camping at the RV park near Stewart - they have a tent section of the campground, and it's well worth staying a couple days so you can drive over the border to Hyder and see the bears at Fish Creek and travel up to Salmon Glacier.